# How to add a tsconfig.json file to Visual Studio 2015 project for compiler options?

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript, configuration-files

Using a TypeScript project in Visual Studio 2015, apparently the tsconfig.json file is used to create compiler options. How is one created to modify compiler options for a TypeScript web application?

For example when I add the below library to TypeScript.

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

Requires --module flag in the compiler options. However, Visual Studio 2015 does not seem to have this file visible in the project. So, I suppose creating one would be sufficient.

Here is file hierarchy:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following `compilerOptions` to `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Please refer to this source project [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/tree/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp) for further help. This is a working angular 2 project. Hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tsconfig.json file and set the following options based on ur needs.

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "system",
    "rootDir": "./app",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```